# What's the best way to handle multiple outgoing connections in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, tcpclient

I have three TCP servers I need to connect to, each with different protocols, but all in nonblocking mode. Right now my plan is essentially opening a new `IO::Socket` per each one and adding them to `IO::Select`, then looping through `can_read()`. The idea is based on how servers are usually written in Perl, but it seems like it could work for clients.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it, furthermore I'm also wondering how I can probe each connection for disconnection, and initiate a reconnection to it without disrupting the other sockets. Any code examples would be a great help, or at least some points in the right direction on how best to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent), or [POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE). Just look through the documentation, it has some nice examples to help you learn your way around.